# WordPress JS- Visual Composer

Tags: plugins

I am trying to make a sense in which I can put the whole functionality of JavaScript [Visual Composer](http://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431) as it is to the front-end of the WordPress site. As I want that user should not use the wp-admin for updating posts and other content. I studied the plugin and try to understand the working, by studying the plugin I understand that it is for the backend only. Here to ask the question is that I want to ask the experts if there is any way to do this.

Please help me in this regard

Comment: Since this is a paid for plugin you'll probably struggle to find support here for it. I had a quick glance myself out of curiosity and there appears to be front end functionality http://vc.wpbakery.com/features/frontend-editor-wordpress/ does this not do what you require?

Comment: not. I want that whole functionality should copy to the front-end as it is in the backend.